# await/async firebase with react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

Im trying to display `console.log('here1')` and enter in the if condition when I finished to check number of children. For now, I have the output :

- here1 false
- here2  true
- here1  true

```
    toggleisModal = async () => {
        const task = this.props.task;
        await firebase.database().ref("Tasks").on("child_added", async (snapshot2) => {
        if (snapshot2.exists()) {
            const countChild = await 
                firebase.database().ref("Tasks").child(snapshot2.key).child(task.taskname);
                countChild.on("value", (snapshot3) => {
                if (snapshot3.numChildren() >= 6) {
                    this.setState({ checkExist: true })
                    console.log("here2 ", this.state.checkExist)
                   }
                })
         }
    })
    console.log("here1 ", this.state.checkExist);


    if (this.state.checkExist === true) {
      this.setState({ showTaskVisible: false });
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ showTaskVisible: !this.state.showTaskVisible });
    }
  };
```

Comment: What isn't working about this code as you expect it to work?

Comment: Defer to Frank, of course, but I don't see how it makes sense to await `on()`

Comment: I want to wait for the end of the research in the database to print here1, and here I can see here1 before and after "here2"